# How to search through POSTed form values using regex and return results

Tags: php, regex, json, search, forms

I'm working on a project where all of the members and their info are stored in a JSON file. I'm in the process of creating a search form and I need help on how to iterate through the members and check to see if there's an exact match or a similar match.

The members are stored in a SESSION variable:

```
$_SESSION['members'] = json_decode($jsonFile);
```

but I'm uncertain how to use regex to check for matches that are similar (and not just exact). For example, if a member's name is "Jonathan", I'd like that result to be returned even if the user searches "Jon". Is regex the correct approach? Any help will be greatly appreciated - thank you!

-Manoj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'd be using a database to store the data rather than JSON so that you can use the LIKE searches, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE 'Jon%'
```

If you absolutely have to use JSON you could loop through all members and use a regexp like

```
preg_match('/^'.$term.'.*/i', $element, $matches);
```

to check them all.

Comment: Hi Paul, yeah I'm stuck working with the JSON file - of which the contents are dumped into an array. Thanks for the regexp - that'll do something similar to the SQL "LIKE" operator?

Comment: What I have written there would work in the same manner as the LIKE example. Of course they don't have to begin at the start, LIKE '%Jon%' would match the word 'jon' anywhere in the field. The equiv regexp could be something like: '/.*'.$term.'.*/i'. What exactly does the array look like and which fields do you wish to search on? preg_grep() is ideal if it's all of them...

Comment: The array if fairly simple. Each member has a name, city and number and the search form would have input fields for name, city and number. And yes, I'd be searching on all of them so based on your suggestion I think I'll go with preg_grep(). I'll be adding more fields for each member in the future, but right now that's what I have.

Answer (score 0):

If the `$jsonFile` contents is an array of some sort, you may find [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/preg_grep) of use, though it doesn't work on multidimensional arrays. You might have have to loop over each individual member record and grep the relevant fields yourself, something like:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['members'] as $idx => $member) {
     ... match relevant fields...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Marc. preg_grep() is what I'll need to use to check for similar matches and not just exact?

Comment: It all depends on how you set up the regex pattern. It won't help you match color/colour, unless you specifically write the pattern for that. If you really want "sounds alike" type matches, you'll have to investigate other things, like the `soundex()` (http://php.net/soundex) function